# create a mirror object, or serialized version of class/object

Tags: json, python-3.x, serialization, dependencies

I want a generic solution to get a structure of booleans to represent structure of an object/class definiton in Python.

**edit: I posted a low quality answer that is probably better to look at for understanding the question**

Only the structure of the object/class, and its member objects, should be visible. Every native singular python variable (eg. floats, strings, ints, booleans) should be represented by only a boolean, always set to true(but for me to be able flip after initialization). If a member variable of the class, is itself a container/iterable/list, it should be scanned for member variables in the same way. The result of this recursive procedure can be a new class or dict where it is easy to map between objects.

This mirrored class or object will be used as a ledger to indicate dependencies of the original class in diffferent contexts. In particular, various functions of other classes have value dependency on the original object, but I need a datastructure to keep track of which out of many numerical members are subject of this dependency.

Any suggestion welcome. My idea would be to serialize the object somehow to a dict, as one does for json dumps, but then just use the object in memory, overriding the content of the variables to boolean

Answer (score 0):

I post an answer to my own question without accepting it, since I hope for something better. I adapted the near-solution found [here](https://gist.github.com/sairamkrish/ab68be93b53b34c98e24908c67dfda0d) to this:

```
def dependency_dict(obj, classkey=None):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        data = {}
        for (k, v) in obj.items():
            data[k] = dependency_dict(v, classkey)
        return data
    elif hasattr(obj, "_ast"):
        return dependency_dict(obj._ast())
    elif hasattr(obj, "__iter__") and not isinstance(obj, str):
        return [dependency_dict(v, classkey) for v in obj]
    elif hasattr(obj, "__dict__"):
        data = dict([(key, dependency_dict(value, classkey)) 
            for key, value in obj.__dict__.items() 
            if not callable(value) and not key.startswith('_')])
        if classkey is not None and hasattr(obj, "__class__"):
            data[classkey] = obj.__class__.__name__
        return data
    else:
        if isinstance(obj, (str,int,float,bool,datetime.datetime)):
            return True
        else:
            return obj
```

Seems to work, but I would prefer a mirrored class that I could reference the boolean members by the exact same interface as the original class. This solution forces a dictionary interface, i.e:

```
mirroredObject = dependency_dict(originalObject)
mirroredObject["list_member"][0]["string_member"] #boolean True value
originalObject.list_member[0].string_member #a string
```